# Generating a simple algebraic expression in swift

Tags: swift, math

I'm looking to create a function that returns a solve for x math equation that can be preformed in ones head (Clearly thats a bit subjective but I'm not sure how else to phrase it).

Example problem: (x - 15)/10 = 6

Note: Only 1 x in the equation

I want to use the operations +, -, *, /, sqrt (Only applied to X -> sqrt(x))

I know that `let mathExpression = NSExpression(format: question)` converts strings into math equations but when solving for x I'm not sure how to go about doing this.

I previously asked [Generating random doable math problems swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43131425/generating-random-doable-math-problems-swift/43132311?noredirect=1#comment73687578_43132311) for non solving for x problems but I'm not sure how to convert that answer into solving for x

Edit: Goal is to generate an equation and have the user solve for the variable.

Comment: Solving equations is not trivial, unless you restrict the allowed input to a very small set. Even with your restricted set of operations, you could have something like `sqrt(x) = 2*x+3`, which *is* doable, but already requires some algebraic transformation. Or what about polynomial equations, which do not have explicit solutions if the degree exceeds 4?

Comment: Is your goal to generate a string like "(x - 15)/10 = 6"? Or is the string supplied by the user, and you're trying to solve for x?

Comment: @Robert Goal is to generate the string and have the user solve for x. The equation cannot be sqrt(x) = 2*x+3 because there should only be 1 x (or variable) in the equation.

Comment: @MartinR see my comment above as to why that equation couldn't be. I am updating the question though

Comment: @huddie96 there is only 1 variable in that equation.   It can appear twice.

Comment: @xaxxon 1 x as in the variable only comes up once

Comment: @huddie96 it's clearly solvable: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt(x)%3D2*x%2B3 <== stackoverflow doesn't create the proper link

Comment: @xaxxon I agree it is solvable but im looking to generate an equation with a single x

Comment: @huddie96 what kind of equation are you looking to generate? linear? All linear equations can be put into the form `y = β1*x + β0`. The problem then becomes generating the coefficients `β0` and `β1`

Comment: @taylorswift Yes a linear equation is okay but also an equation where theres a sqrt over the variable x

Comment: The first step would be to (unambiguously) define the possible input. Then you need a parser which parses the input string into some internal representation, like the one used in your previous question. *Then* you can start solving the expression for `x`. – Therefore the question in its current form seems too broad to me.

Comment: @MartinR he wants to *generate* equations, not solve them. I’m guessing it’s for some sort of electronic homework problem generator.

Comment: It's for an app I'm building to provide multiple choice questions not homework but yes I'm looking to generate questions

Comment: @huddie96: Should your program *generate* equations or *solve* equations? – You initially say "create a function that returns a solve for x", but later "have the user solve".

Comment: @MartinR returns a solve for x math equation. That's a. Equation not an answer. Sorry for the miscommunication

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since all you want is a string representing an equation and a value for x, you don't need to do any solving. Just start with x and transform it until you have a nice equation. Here's a sample: (copy and paste it into a Playground to try it out)

```
import UIKit

enum Operation: String {
    case addition = "+"
    case subtraction = "-"
    case multiplication = "*"
    case division = "/"


    static func all() -> [Operation] {
        return [.addition, .subtraction, .multiplication, .division]
    }

    static func random() -> Operation {
        let all = Operation.all()
        let selection = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(all.count)))
        return all[selection]
    }

}


func addNewTerm(formula: String, result: Int) -> (formula: String, result: Int) {
    // choose a random number and operation
    let operation = Operation.random()
    let number = chooseRandomNumberFor(operation: operation, on: result)
    // apply to the left side
    let newFormula = applyTermTo(formula: formula, number: number, operation: operation)
    // apply to the right side
    let newResult = applyTermTo(result: result, number: number, operation: operation)
    return (newFormula, newResult)
}

func applyTermTo(formula: String, number:Int, operation:Operation) -> String {
    return "\(formula) \(operation.rawValue) \(number)"
}

func applyTermTo(result: Int, number:Int, operation:Operation) -> Int {
    switch(operation) {
    case .addition: return result + number
    case .subtraction: return result - number
    case .multiplication: return result * number
    case .division: return result / number
    }
}

func chooseRandomNumberFor(operation: Operation, on number: Int) -> Int {
    switch(operation) {
    case .addition, .subtraction, .multiplication:
        return Int(arc4random_uniform(10) + 1)
    case .division:
        // add code here to find integer factors
        return 1
    }
}


func generateFormula(_ numTerms:Int = 1) -> (String, Int) {
    let x = Int(arc4random_uniform(10))
    var leftSide = "x"
    var result = x

    for i in 1...numTerms {
        (leftSide, result) = addNewTerm(formula: leftSide, result: result)
        if i < numTerms {
            leftSide = "(" + leftSide + ")"
        }
    }

    let formula = "\(leftSide) = \(result)"

    return (formula, x)
}

func printFormula(_ numTerms:Int = 1) {
    let (formula, x) = generateFormula(numTerms)
    print(formula, "                      x = ", x)
}


for i in 1...30 {
    printFormula(Int(arc4random_uniform(3)) + 1)
}
```

There are some things missing. The sqrt() function will have to be implemented separately. And for division to be useful, you'll have to add in a system to find factors (since you presumably want the results to be integers). Depending on what sort of output you want, there's a lot more work to do, but this should get you started.

Here's sample output:

```
(x + 10) - 5 = 11                       x =  6
((x + 6) + 6) - 1 = 20                       x =  9
x - 2 = 5                       x =  7
((x + 3) * 5) - 6 = 39                       x =  6
(x / 1) + 6 = 11                       x =  5
(x * 6) * 3 = 54                       x =  3
x * 9 = 54                       x =  6
((x / 1) - 6) + 8 = 11                       x =  9
```

Comment: I'll try when I get to my computer. Why do some output just x?

Comment: @huddie96 The sample output shows the generated equation on the left, value of x on the right.

Comment: Oh it's a problem with the stackoverflow app. My apologizes. It doesn't show what x = for some of the outputs

Comment: @huddie96 Division has to be by an integral factor to yield an int. I didn't write code to find factors, but I'm sure you can figure that out. Look for the comment that says "add code here to find integer factors".

Comment: Im looking to find integer factor of what number at that points?

Comment: @huddie96 The current result. In that function (chooseRandomNumberFor) it's the variable "number".

Comment: Is it possible for it to return a negative number?

Comment: @huddie96 Yes it can be negative.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, let’s assume from you saying “*Note: Only 1 x in the equation*” that what you want is a linear equation of the form `y = 0 = β1*x + β0`, where `β0` and `β1` are the slope and intercept coefficients, respectively.

The inverse of (or solution to) any linear equation is given by `x = -β0/β1`. So what you really need to do is generate random integers `β0` and `β1` to create your equation. But since it should be “solvable” in someone’s head, you probably want `β0` to be divisible by `β1`, and furthermore, for `β1` and `β0/β1` to be less than or equal to `12`, since this is the upper limit of the commonly known multiplication tables. In this case, just generate a random integer `β1 ≤ 12`, and `β0` equal to `β1` times some integer `n`, `0 ≤ n ≤ 12`.

If you want to allow simple fractional solutions like `2/3`, just multiply the denominator and the numerator into `β0` and `β1`, respectively, taking care to prevent the numerator or denominator from getting too large (`12` is again a good limit).

Since you probably want to make `y` non-zero, just generate a third random integer `y` between `-12` and `12`, and change your output equation to `y = β1*x + β0 + y`.

Since you mentioned `√` could occur over the `x` variable only, that is pretty easy to add; the solution (to `0 = β1*sqrt(x) + β0`) is just `x = (β0/β1)**2`.

Here is some very simple (and very problematic) code for generating random integers to get you started:

```
import func Glibc.srand
import func Glibc.rand
import func Glibc.time

srand(UInt32(time(nil)))
print(rand() % 12)
```

There are a great many answers on this website that deal with [better ways to generate random integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822323/how-to-generate-a-random-number-in-c).